# How to keep a wxpython frame always on screen?

Tags: python, wxpython

I made a music player, Once the main frame is iconized another frame appears and once that frame is iconized a smaller frame appears. Is there a way to get the last, small frame, to always be on the screen? now if I click outside of the frame it disappears until I click on it in the taskbar. I want it to always be on screen until the user clicks a button to open up the frame before the final, small frame.

Comment: Would a modal dialog work instead?

Comment: I suppose it could if it will stay on the screen at all times?

Comment: http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Dialog-class.html

Comment: Would it stay on the screen even is I click outside of the frame?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

Comment: Ok so I changed the frame to a dialog, how do i make it a modal dialog? Because just as a dialog it still does what I dont want it to

Comment: it sounds like this is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497482/wxpython-making-a-frame-be-on-top-of-everything

Answer (score 0):

To make the dialog stay in the foreground until the user interacts with it use the `ShowModal()` method:

> There are two types of dialogs. Modal and modeless. Modal dialog does
>   not allow a user to work with the rest of the application until it is
>   destroyed. Modal dialogs are created with the ShowModal() method.
>   Dialogs are modeless when called with Show().

http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial/

If you just want the window to stay in the foreground, you can use the `setFocus()` method on the dialog because it is a child of the `Window` class:

```
SetFocus(self)
```

> Set's the focus to this window, allowing it to receive keyboard input.

http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#SetFocus

Comment: so here is my code for my dialog box. where would I use the ShowModal() at?

Comment: `class CollapseButton(wx.Dialog):
    
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Show Controls', size=(90,25), pos=(1180,870), style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.STAY_ON_TOP|wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR)

        self.my_parent2 = parent
        decollapse = wx.Button(self, -1, "Show Controls", pos=(0,0))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.deCollapse, decollapse)

    def deCollapse(self, event):
            self.my_parent2.Show()
            self.Destroy()`

Comment: Try `self.ShowModal()` or `self.my_parent2.ShowModal()`

Comment: It still disappears once I click out of the frame :/

Comment: Store the `wx.Dialog.__init__(..)` in a variable, like so: `dlg = wx.Dialog.__init__(..)` then do `dlg.ShowModal()`

Comment: This is what I did in the parent window.     `def mini(self, event):
        self.Hide()
        self.new = CollapseButton(self, -1)
        self.new.ShowModal()`

Comment: So I call the small window from the parent once the parent is minimized