# wxPython: Making a frame be on top of everything

Tags: windows, user-interface, wxpython, z-order, always-on-top

I want my frame to be always on top, but I want it to be really on top. I want no other windows to hide it, even if they are also "always on top". I'm using `wx.STAY_ON_TOP` and `wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT`, but still there are windows that appear on top of mine. Also, the taskbar appears on top of my frame, while I'd like it to be behind my frame.

I've tried a lot of things that didn't work, detailed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/wxpython-users/on%2420top/wxpython-users/LDqVoR6jVCo/ZLReBWApOWwJ).

Any idea how to make my frame really on top?

Comment: Would making it full screen and then disallowing minimization suffice? Are you only targeting Windows or does the answer need to also work on Gtk and Mac?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to access the task bar at all?

Comment: @PaulMcNett The user doesn't need to be able to access the task bar. Solution is expected to be Windows-only. Full-screen isn't an option because some of the time the frame shouldn't be full-screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because their is no standard method in doing so, as it is most often an undesired effect, you can possibly achieve this by frequently setting the topmost flag again to "overrule" any other applications going for the topmost position. You could do this using a timer which sets the value every x ms, or you can try and only set the ontop flag again when the window has lost focus. The events to set the ontop flag are:

```
EVT_SET_FOCUS 
EVT_KILL_FOCUS
```

Comment: Progress! Now my app is in a constant struggle with Rosetta Stone, that's apparently doing the same thing, constantly making itself on top. The result of this tug of war is that the entire screen flickers, making the whole computer unusable. I'm thinking that the solution might be to stop Rosetta Stone from doing this. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @RamRachum You could try to constantly remove the always on top flag of Rosetta Stone, but i'm not sure how to do that from Python, I do know how to do it from AutoIt: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinSetOnTop.htm

But like you already said, it will keep being a tug of war, I don't think you can actually make Rosetta Stone forfeit.

Comment: Great! I used AHK to make a script that makes the active application not always on top, and I just use it on Rosetta Stone manually, and it works. Now my app is on top of Rosetta Stone.

Comment: The AHK script is essentially: `+^#a::    WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, A    Return`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
wx.Frame.SetFocus()
```